# How to download .xlsx which is conditionally generated in .rmd in Shiny APP?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, knitr, xlsx

I am working on a `shiny` app which is oriented toward knitting downloadable rmd files, but sometimes particular .rmd file conditionally generates preprocessed .xlsx files. The .rmd files are downloaded without problems, but .xlsx file/s disappear (but I see it in the temporary app folder where the app.r, and the .rmd file are also). Any searching directions? How to download (in the course of downloading .rmd report) also that .xlsx?

I expect that the .xlsx file will be downloaded with knitted .rmd file.